# Double sum in mathematica

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation

It may look like a stupid question, but I was really confused by how double sums works in mathematica:
[image]

After simplification, the function actually has nothing to do with n2?

Also, when I manually calculate Kin[1,1], which is n1=n2=1, it should be m1=m2=0. Then Kin[1,1] should be (-1) * B(2,2) * B(2,2) * B(0,0) * (-2) =2, but mathematica gives 4. What is wrong here?

UPDATE1:
For copy-and-paste-able code, see here:

```
Kin[n1_, n2_] = Sum[
           (-1)^(m1 + m2 + 1)*Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*
           Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*Binomial[m1 + m2, m1]*
          ((m1 - m2)^2 - m1 - m2 - 2), 
                {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}]
```

UPDATE2:
Thanks for the answers! I got the desired answer, but I'm still confused by how MMA simplifies the expression of Kin, if I use Simplify:

```
  Simplify[Sum[
            (-1)^(m1 + m2 + 1)*Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*
            Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*Binomial[m1 + m2, m1]*
           ((m1 - m2)^2 - m1 - m2 - 2), 
                 {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}]]
```

I still get the result as in Out[15] in the screenshot. Any idea why it goes wrong?

Comment: Please post copy-and-paste-able code, properly formatted in code blocks, rather than screenshots of your code. Edit your post by clicking the grey edit button below your post, and click the grey question mark on the right side of the editing toolbar for formatting help.

Comment: @James, your code does not work when pasted back. Please see here: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584/27951

Comment: Thanks guys! Really helpful link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the symbolic calculation is correct, but I would suggest that you don't pre-calculate the value of the sum; rather, let the sum be calculated when the values of $n_1$ and $n_2$ are on hand by using `SetDelayed` in your definition of `K1`:

```
Clear[Kin]
Kin[n1_, n2_] := 
 Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + 1) * Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2] * Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2] *
   Binomial[m1 + m2, m1] * ((m1 - m2)^2 - m1 - m2 - 2), {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}]
```

The calculated value for `Kin[1, 1]` is then what you expected:

```
Kin[1, 1]
(* Out: 2 *)
```

The value of `Kin` also depends on the value of $n_2$, as you expected:

```
Kin[1, 2]
(* Out: 4 *)
```

Comment: Thanks! A useful link here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html

Answer (score 0):

When you are first defining `Kin[n1_,n2_]` you are not specifying anything about `n1` or `n2`. For simpler cases MMA returns `ConditionalExpression`. However, as much I have seen, for complicated evaluation MMA goes with an approximation which is more widely applicable (in your case `n1,n2>1`).

To bypass this, you can always put `Assumptions` with your evaluation.

```
Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + 1)*Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*
  Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*Binomial[m1 + m2, m1]*((m1 - m2)^2 - m1 - m2 - 2),
 {m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}, Assumptions -> {n1 ==  1, n2 == 1}]
```

> 2

Or you can go with the preassigned values.

```
Block[{n1 = 1, n2 = 1}, 
Sum[(-1)^(m1 + m2 + 1)*Binomial[n1 + 1, m1 + 2]*
 Binomial[n2 + 1, m2 + 2]*Binomial[m1 + m2, m1]*((m1 - m2)^2 - m1 - m2 - 2),
{m1, 0, n1 - 1}, {m2, 0, n2 - 1}]]
```

> 2